# Pandas dataframe: Get value pairs from subsets of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4], \
                    "name": ["call", "response", "call", "call", "response", "call", "call", "response", "response"]})
```

```
    id  name
0   1   call
1   1   response
2   2   call
3   2   call
4   2   response
5   3   call
6   4   call
7   4   response
8   4   response
```

And I'm trying to extract a call - response pair, where the first response after call is the right pattern. Call and responses pairs are in their own subsets with `id` like so:

```
    id  name
0   1   call
1   1   response
3   2   call
4   2   response
6   4   call
7   4   response
```

Ideally I'd keep the `indexes` in the dataframe so I can use `df.loc` with indexes later.

What I have tried is to go through the `df` in subsets and `apply` something or use `rolling window`. But have only succeeded to get errors.

```
unique_ids = df.id.unique()

for unique_id in unique_ids :
    df.query('id== @unique_id').apply(something))
```

I have yet to discover something that could work specifically with `subsets` of dataframe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) with compare values by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for check equality and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) :

```
m1 = df['name'].eq('call') & df.groupby('id')['name'].shift(-1).eq('response')
m2 = df['name'].eq('response') & df.groupby('id')['name'].shift().eq('call')
df2 = df[m1 | m2]

print (df2)
   id      name
0   1      call
1   1  response
3   2      call
4   2  response
6   4      call
7   4  response
```

Comment: @Corralien, they want pairs where one index with name 'call' is followed immediately by an index with the same id and name 'response.' They do not want the last response with the same id. This is shown in the intended output that OP put in their question.